# How to transmit with a virtual webcam driver in .NET

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, webcam, skype

Requirement:

I would like to interface my .NET application to a "virtual webcam driver" for the purposes of SENDING image frames.

I'm happy to use an open source .NET or COM component if that exists

or indeed implement a "webcam driver" from scratch if someone can point me in the right direction.

My first priority is the functionality.

My second priority is low dependancy on 3rd party libraries and tech (aside from .NET of course ;) )

I'd prefer not to involve directshow if possible?

Comment: @abcdefghi: I am not sure why you chose to edit an old question rather than ask yours. Even though it looks similar, yours is different and there is little to add to existing answer below. There is no .NET interface into API in question. You will have to deal with native code development, and most likely IPC as well.

Comment: Roman: most likely for the badge for rewarding a bounty on someone else's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to end up with a virtual camera, important is what APIs you would like to expose it through. In most cases the applications will look for cameras - where they pick your virtual one - through `DirectShow` you tend to avoid.

Hence, you need to either deal with DirectShow directly, or use a third party middleware component which can grab/accept your data and deliver it through DirectShow.

Comment: can you add more details?

Comment: @abcdefghi: You did see my comment above, didn't you (just to make sure)?